# running file with exec or subprocess with python inputs

Tags: python, subprocess

My file is

```
#Requesting input of price from the cashier in dollars and cents
price = round(100 * float(input("Enter the price of item bought:")))

#Requesting input of amount of money given to the cashier in dollars and cents
pay = round(100 * float(input("Enter the amount of money you gave the cashier:")))

# Declare/initialize variables and make calculations
change = pay - price
dollars = int(change / 100)
quarters = int((change - dollars * 100) / 25)
dimes = int((change- dollars * 100 - (25 * quarters)) / 10)
nickels = int((change - dollars * 100 - (25 * quarters) - (10 * dimes)) / 5)
pennies = int(change - dollars * 100 - (25 * quarters) - (10 * dimes) - (5 * nickels))

# Print the output/results of calculations 
print("Your change:")
print("   dollars      ", dollars)
print("   quarters     ", quarters)
print("   dimes        ", dimes)
print("   nickels      ", nickels)
print("   pennies      ", pennies)
print("Thank you for your business")
```

I have to loop over 'n' such files in the directory and run them with input 1 and 5. I was trying to create a simple script to do it and I tried:

```
exec(open(i).read())
```

or

```
os.system(f"{i} 1 2")
```

with using sys.argv but it doesn't work

I tried to use the `subprocess` library as:

```
subprocess.call(f'python3 {i} 1 2')
```

Doesn't work, the program stops and asks for the user's input

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["python",f"{i}"],text=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE) #, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate("1")
```

Doesn't work, throws an error that I am trying to access a closed file.

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, f'{i}', '1.57', '5'])
```

Does not work. I can see the lines below in the terminal. I believe that after not getting the first input, the program stops.

```
Change Calculator
Enter the price of the item bought
```

I would appreciate any help how to do it :) I cannot really edit the files I have and I also have a bunch of them. I went through some tips about `subprocess` described on the forum but I did not find the one which works for me. Also if you know the way how to capture what program is printing, I would be grateful for a tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok answer is easy

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["python",f"{i}"],text=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE) #, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate("1 \n 2",timeout=None)
```